# avoid caching of page in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I am using an iframe to show the child pages.In that one one particular page contains hidden div and i am showing it as a pop-up like thing with javascript by changing the visibility of the hidden div.

Problem is before showing the hidden div , some manipulations are done at server level and I am calling the div from C# code after the manipulations like

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "javascript:OpenModelPopup('cb','cs');", true);
```

so the page is getting posted back and the div is shown.

after this, after going to next page if i click browser back it shows that page with that hidden div and on next click of browser back gives the page without hidden div.

but I want to show only the initial stage of the page ie. without showing the hidden div
that stage with hidden div should not be cached or it should not be shown on click of browser back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need both the no-cache and no-store directives to force browsers to reload the page.  Your mileage may vary from browser to browser though.